# Is the space of $p$-geometric rough paths is Homeomorphic to Frechet Space

Tags: gn.general-topology, rough-paths

Let $\Omega G^p([0,T];\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a space of $p$-geometric rough paths with values in $\mathbb{R}^n$.   Is $\Omega G^p([0,T];\mathbb{R}^n)$ homeomorphic to some Fr\'{e}chet space?

Comment: Does your space have a suitable convexity structure?

Comment: No, but why would that matter, since the homeomorphism I'm looking for need not be linear.

Comment: Simple for spaces with additional (convex or group) structure there are many results establishing their topological equivalence to Frechet spaces.